# How to initialize spring list bean from a text file

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I need to populate a spring bean with values (lines) from a text file. 
I know how to to populate it by typing the values  into the definition:

```
<property name="lists">
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetListClass">
            <value>java.util.ArrayList</value>
        </property>
        <property name="sourceList">
            <list>
                <value>155</value>
                <value>255</value>
                <value>333</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

But in my case I have a file that looks like this:

```
155
255
333
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
@Value("#{'${string.list}'.split(',')}") 
 private List<String> sourcelist;
```

In the bean and read the value string.list from the property file separated by a , delimiter.

Comment: Sorry, can't get how to do this. Can you pls update my configuration? As well, why are you splitting by a comma?

Comment: Refer to this link ...http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert-Spring-config

Comment: sorry, this doesn't answer the question.